# Add more than one range to combobox

Tags: excel, vba

I have a combobox and I want to add E1 and then another range somewhere between E2 and E13 depending on some variables. But what happens is that the entire range is added, E1:E13. This is the code:

```
Sheets("GraphChoice").MonthComboBox.AddList = Sheets("FormInfo").Range("E1", "E" & startmonth + 1 & ":E13")
```

Is it possible to add more than one range to a combobox?

Comment: i suggest to load the final data into a contiguous range off to the side and have the combobox reference that range. Or you can make a dynamic named range as well possibly and use that.

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work `Sheets("GrafChoice").MonthComboBox..List = Application.Union(Sheets("FormInfo").Range("E1"), Sheets("FormInfo").Range("E4:E13"))` I got the error (translated) : "Invalid index for attribute matrix"

Comment: What type of the combobox: ActiveX control or Form control?

Comment: I'll try your suggestion Scott, seems like it would work!

Comment: It's an ActiveX control

Comment: `Sheets("GraphChoice").MonthComboBox.AddList = Sheets("FormInfo").Range("E1, E" & startmonth + 1 & ":E13")`

Comment: Sure you meant the `.List` property in above comment @ScottCraner :-)

Comment: @T.M. Even .List doesn't work directly. as the range is non-adjacent in this case. This throws an error. If the range is one range this works `Sheets("GraphChoice").MonthComboBox.List = Sheets("FormInfo").Range("E1:E5").Value`

Comment: Correct, of course; referred to the `.AddList` method(?) above which I don't know. @YasserKhalil

Comment: Sorry, `.AddList` was a misspelling. I meant `.List` . List is also the one I'm using in my code, I think I tried .AddList just to see if it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, e, r As Range, i As Long
With Sheets("FormInfo")
    Set r = Application.Union(.Range("E1"), .Range("E4:E13"))
    ReDim a(1 To r.Cells.Count)
    For Each e In r
        i = i + 1
        a(i) = e
    Next e
    Sheets("GraphChoice").MonthComboBox.List = a
End With
End Sub
```